# Configuration element not is not declared ssrs

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I took this from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services-LoadTest).

Th thing is I am trying to adapt it and use it. The problem resides that I get the error that Configuration element is not declared. I have searched but iton the internet but I find things of configuration instead of the following structure of XML.

It is as if it needs something to tell it what the schema is.

```
  <Configuration>
 <ReportServerUrl>http://ssrs.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/ReportServer</ReportServerUrl>
<ReportPortalUrl>http://ssrs.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/Reports</ReportPortalUrl>
  <PowerBIUrl>http://ssrs.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com/powerbi/api/explore/reports</PowerBIUrl>
<DatasourceDatabaseServer>ssrs-datasource</DatasourceDatabaseServer>
<ExecutionAccount>contoso\ProvideAUser</ExecutionAccount>
<ExecutionAccountPwd>ProvideAPassword</ExecutionAccountPwd>
<DatasourceSQLUser>ProvideASQLUser</DatasourceSQLUser>
<DatasourceSQLPassword>ProvideASQLPassword</DatasourceSQLPassword>
```

Comment: I fix it. It is not necessary for Visual Studio to understand the schema of the xml for the proyect to work. The thing is the DatasourceDatabaseServer must be the name of the sql server, and I was confusing it with the reporting service name. Aditionally I would like to comment that the data source user can be from tha active directory or a sql server user.